# Loop with componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing a self invoking function from `App` Component into `getBgColor` function of `WeatherForecast` Component. This grabs a value from the child component `WeatherForecast` and passes it into `App` Component to update `this.state.appColorClass`.

*`getBgColor` function is inside `componentDidUpdate()` which creates a loop and crashes the broweser. New to react and not sure how to solve this.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { appColorClass: 'app-bg1' };
  }

  setAppColor(colorClass) {
    alert("set className");
    this.setState({ appColorClass: colorClass });
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div className={"app-container " + this.state.appColorClass}>
      <div className="main-wrapper">

          <WeatherForecast getBgColor={color => this.setAppColor(color)} />

      </div>   
    </div> 
    );
  }
}


class WeatherForecast extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('Component DID UPDATE!')
      //The function `setAppColor` from `App` component is passed into `getBgColor`
      this.props.getBgColor(this.appColor(this.props.weather));
  }

  appColor(weatherData) {
    console.log("app color working");

    let temp = 0;
    if ( typeof weatherData === 'undefined' || weatherData === null ) {
      console.log(" initial Color went through");
      return 'app-bg1';
    }
    temp = Math.round(weatherData.list[0].main.temp - 273.15);
    if (temp <= -30) {
        return "app-bg1";
    }
    if (temp >= -29 && temp <= -21) {
        return "app-bg2";
    }
    if (temp >= -20 && temp <= -11) {
        return "app-bg3";
    }
    if (temp >= -10 && temp <= 4) {
        return "app-bg4";
    }
    if (temp >= 5 && temp <= 15) {
        return "app-bg5";
    }
    if (temp >= 16 && temp <= 24) {
        return "app-bg6";
    }
    if (temp >= 25 && temp <= 32) {
        return "app-bg7";
    }
    if (temp >= 33 && temp <= 38) {
        return "app-bg8";
    }
    if (temp >= 39) {
        return "app-bg9";
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="text-center col-xs-12">
         <h1 id="temp">{this.displayTemp(this.props.weather)}<sup>&deg;</sup></h1>
         <h1>{this.displayCity(this.props.weather)}</h1> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add a shouldComponentUpdate to WeatherForecast and return false when this.props.weather === nextProps.weather. Or depending on what you are trying to do, move the call of getBgColor to componentDidMount so that it will be called only once.

Comment: `<WeatherForecast getBgColor={color => this.setAppColor(color)} />` could just be `<WeatherForecast getBgColor={this.setAppColor} />`, no need for the additional function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with Johnny Klironomos's suggestion which returned true or false according to the Property value in `shouldComponentUpdate`.

*`this.props.weather` is undefined once the app loads because the user needs to pick a city to view its weather.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if(this.props.weather === 'undefined'){
      return true
    }
    return this.props.weather !== nextProps.weather
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop is recursive because after the `WeatherForecast` component mounts (updating) it calls the `getBgColor` prop, which sets parent state, which triggers a child update, which calls `getBgColor`... and you get the picture.

Honestly, I would probably advise moving the logic around a little... since `weather` is passed in as a prop and then the color is passed back up, it would seem more "React" like to handle that in the parent component. It's simpler to follow when data flows downstream. Assuming your requirements lead you to this position, adding a simple check in the `setAppColor` would solve the issue.

```
setAppColor(colorClass) {
  alert("set className");
  // only set state if it's changing
  if (colorClass != this.state.appColorClass) {
    this.setState({ appColorClass: colorClass });
  }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid writing another mapStateToProps of `state.weather` in the `App` component since I already had it in the `WeatherForecast` component. This was more of a learning experience/exercise in order to learn how to pass child properties to their parent. Thanks for the suggestion of the if statement in setAppColor :)